# Centering of watermark at front page

Tags: horizontal-alignment, watermark

I have now modified the document to what I think is a MWE and also realized where it all goes wrong, but I still don't know why. Therefore I will update the post.

I am trying to make a watermark on the front page to be centered but have the problem that it ends up in the left side of the document. What is wrong with the coding? I have just used a precoded script and tried to insert my changes into that. The coding is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{tikz}
\SetWatermarkText{\tikz{\node[opacity=0.4]{\includegraphics{test_picture}};}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkScale{1}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0,1,0}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Here it all works fine and the watermark is in the middle, but as I add this part

```
\usepackage{vmargin}
\setmarginsrb{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{2.5 cm}{2.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}{1 cm}{1.5 cm}
```

It does not and the picture shrinks and ends up on the left. So my question is: what does this coding do, is it important for the rest of the document (I'm writing a report) and what can be done so that the watermark will end up in the right size and position?

Thank you!
Mikael

Comment: Hi mikael, could you provide a MWE please?

Comment: I'm sorry, new to this, what is an MWE?

Comment: it's a full example wich can be compiled. compare [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?lq=1)

Comment: Aha.. So you want me to get rid of the things that is not necessary for the actual problem? The problem is that I am not sure what is what since I have used a template for the writing and just copy pasted the \setwatermark-thingy.. Sorry!

Comment: I have now created a MWE, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly identified, the error is introduced by [`vmargin`](http://ctan.org/pkg/vmargin).  I had never heard of this package until now, and reading the description, it seems to have been superseded by [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry).

I'm not sure how `vmargin` works, because for some reason, it was changing the paper size.  I tried to implement similar settings in geometry to produce a similar output, but geometry doesn't adjust the paper size when adjusting various heights and margins.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[firstpage]{draftwatermark}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[
  hmargin=2.5cm,
  vmargin={1cm,2.5cm},
  headheight=1cm,
  headsep=1.5cm,
  footskip=1.5cm,
]{geometry}

\SetWatermarkText{\tikz{\node[opacity=0.2]{\includegraphics{example-image-a}};}}
\SetWatermarkAngle{0}
\SetWatermarkScale{1}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0,1,0}

\begin{document}
Test
\end{document}
```

Here's the output:

[image: output]

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick answer. I have now tried your geometry package and it works great!  Just curious about the different commands, what do they all adjust? I'm thinking about these:
  hmargin=2.5cm,
  vmargin={1cm,2.5cm},
  headheight=1cm,
  headsep=1.5cm,
  footskip=1.5cm,

Furthermore I wonder if it is possible to move the watermark vertically somehow? Not horizontally which was the problem before. Thank you again!

Comment: You can read all about how [`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) works by looking at the package documentation (just follow the link).  That will describe what `hmargin`, `vmargin`, etc. do.  To move it vertically up, you can use `\node[text height=3cm]`.  Play around with the distance (you can even use negative numbers!).

Comment: Thank you again! I am not surehow to insert the node-code into it all. Where are you supposed to put it?

Comment: Oh, sorry that wasn't clear.  Just add the `text height=3cm` option to the existing node, next to `opacity=0.2` (and you should separate both options with a comma).

Comment: No worries, if I was better at this I would have been able to figure that out. But now it's working fine. Thanks, this is great! Can I somehow add an extra of those medals that you have by your name or something? Because this has been very helpful!

Comment: Haha, if an answer is helpful, make sure to give it an upvote with the arrows next to the answer, and you can (and should) mark the definitive answer with the tick.  This gives the person who posted the question and yourself some reputation points :)

Comment: Hmm.. Ok, I tried, but my reputation is too low to show any difference. That's sad. How do you improve your rep?

Comment: No worries :)  You can read the [start guide for TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) which should get you started.  You get reps by providing good content, either in the form of good and well-posed questions or answers which others then upvote.  You also get some reps by accepting an answers :)  As you get more reps, you get more privileges because TeX.SX is entirely run by volunteers.

Comment: Great, then I know. Thanks! I'll doo what I can. :)